# How to convert a local html file to pdf with gif images in it?

Tags: html, image, pdf, gif

I have an html file that sources gif images from within my Computer.
Is there a way i can convert it to a still pdf and use it anywhere else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider using a Document Conversion library that can render the HTML page with the GIF images then converts the displayed objects into a PDF output. As an example, the LEADTOOLS [Document Converter](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter) class is able to convert from an HTML to PDF while maintaining the text and appearance as displayed in the browser. (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor)